# something wrong with recaptcha style

Tags: css, styles, recaptcha

i'm using recaptcha in this page http://www.mawk3y.net/news2/contactus.php but suddenly style has been changed without any reason here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean'
  };
</script>

<?php
  require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
  $publickey = "key here"; 
 echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

Comment: Did't get your need. which style changed explain more..

Comment: if you look at the captcha you'll see it became so wide displaying a scrollbar and using inspect element I tried to make it smaller but didn't work

Comment: That table having capcha form have fixed width to 600px with as inline see it..

Comment: if you mean the main table it has no style it had width only set to 600

Comment: Yep it calulated as 1041px..the problem is rise from there

Comment: I think the width of the recaptcha extends the width of the table. I've set the width of the table to 600!important but didn't work

Comment: besides recapthca width should always be fixed not expanding like this

Answer (score 1):

Just moved the recaptcha out of the main div containing the table and it has no problem now I didn't know the reason